# Map with json to a List with specific key

Tags: groovy

I have managed to get out a json list and get a key out from the json.

I am working on how to put every version value in a list. How do I do that from a Map?

```
Map convertedJSONMap = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(data)

//If you have the nodes then fetch the first one only
if(convertedJSONMap."items"){
    println "Version : " + convertedJSONMap."items"[0]."version"
}
```

So what I need is some kind of foreach loop that is going to throw the Map and just getting the items. version from each and put it in a list. How?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy has [`Collection.collect(closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) that can be used to transform a list of values of one type to a list of new values. Consider the following example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
    "items": [
        {"id": "ID-001", "version": "1.23", "name": "Something"},
        {"id": "ID-002", "version": "1.14.0", "name": "Foo Bar"},
        {"id": "ID-003", "version": "2.11", "name": "Something else"},
        {"id": "ID-004", "version": "8.0", "name": "ABC"},
        {"id": "ID-005", "version": "2.32", "name": "Empty"},
        {"id": "ID-006", "version": "4.11.2.3", "name": "Null"}
    ]
}'''

def convertedJSONMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def list = convertedJSONMap.items.collect { it.version }

println list.inspect()
```

Output:

```
['1.23', '1.14.0', '2.11', '8.0', '2.32', '4.11.2.3']
```

Groovy also provides [spread operator `*.`](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) which can simplify this example to something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
    "items": [
        {"id": "ID-001", "version": "1.23", "name": "Something"},
        {"id": "ID-002", "version": "1.14.0", "name": "Foo Bar"},
        {"id": "ID-003", "version": "2.11", "name": "Something else"},
        {"id": "ID-004", "version": "8.0", "name": "ABC"},
        {"id": "ID-005", "version": "2.32", "name": "Empty"},
        {"id": "ID-006", "version": "4.11.2.3", "name": "Null"}
    ]
}'''

def convertedJSONMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def list = convertedJSONMap.items*.version

println list.inspect()
```

Or even this (you can replace `*.version` with just `.version`):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
    "items": [
        {"id": "ID-001", "version": "1.23", "name": "Something"},
        {"id": "ID-002", "version": "1.14.0", "name": "Foo Bar"},
        {"id": "ID-003", "version": "2.11", "name": "Something else"},
        {"id": "ID-004", "version": "8.0", "name": "ABC"},
        {"id": "ID-005", "version": "2.32", "name": "Empty"},
        {"id": "ID-006", "version": "4.11.2.3", "name": "Null"}
    ]
}'''

def convertedJSONMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def list = convertedJSONMap.items.version

println list.inspect()
```

All examples produce the same output.

Comment: Absolutly perfect answer. Thx